# How to extract document AIP labels using MIP SDK without auth/offline?

Tags: c, sdk, azure-information-protection

I want to get AIP labels assigned to a file using MIP SDK, but it needs the auth token to get it. Is their any way I can extract the label without token or web connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

Since office files are ZIP you can extract docProps/custom.xml with list of applied labels. But that work for unprotected files only.

For protected files similar xml attached non-encrypted into the end of file.